# Reset variable after ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have two ajax functions looking like this :

```
  $("body").on("click", ".follow", function() {
    var followingId = $(this).data("following");
    var followData = {"following_id" : followingId}
    $(this).addClass('disabled');
    $.ajax({
      url: "/users/follow/",
      type: "POST",
      data: followData,
      dataType: 'json',
      context: this,
      error: function () {},
      success : function (response) {
    $(this).addClass('unfollow');
    $(this).attr('data-unfollow', response.row_id);
    $(this).removeClass('follow');
      }
    });
  });

  $("body").on("click", ".unfollow", function() {
    var unfollowId = $(this).data("unfollow");
    var unfollowData = {"row_id" : unfollowId};
    $(this).addClass('disabled');
    $.ajax({
      url: "/users/unfollow/",
      type: "POST",
      data: unfollowData,
      context: this,
      error: function () {},
      success : function () {
        $(this).removeClass('disabled');
        $(this).addClass('follow');
        $(this).removeClass('unfollow');
      }
    });
  });
```

When I "follow" an user, I get the "row_id" (let's say row_id n°1) as a response and set it as unfollow-data. If I "unfollow" the user, the row_id n°1 if sent. It's normal.

If I try following again, I get a new row_id (let's say row n°2) as a response. That's also normal. But If I want to unfollow again, row_id n°1 is sent !
I guess I should update

```
var unfollowId = $(this).data("unfollow");
```

(In the html the value has changed to row_id n°2), but when I post row_id n°1 is sent.

I can I achieve this ?

Many thanks !

Comment: Can't tell what you're asking.

Comment: When I use the first function I get a row_id as a response. I set it as a data attribute. If I reuse the first function, I get a new row_id, that I set as data attribute, but If I then use the second function, the row_id sent is still the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first function, change this:

```
$(this).attr('data-unfollow', response.row_id);
```

to this:

```
$(this).data('unfollow', response.row_id);
```

---

FYI, you can use jQuery chaining so a sequence like this:

```
$(this).removeClass('disabled');
$(this).addClass('follow');
$(this).removeClass('unfollow');
```

can be done more efficiently like this:

```
$(this).removeClass('disabled').addClass('follow').removeClass('unfollow');
```

or, if you like them on separate lines:

```
$(this).removeClass('disabled')
    .addClass('follow')
    .removeClass('unfollow');
```

Comment: Holly molly it works ! Thanks so much ! Can you please explain the difference ?

Comment: @Ziplo - I'm not 100% sure of the explanation without some debugging.  I know it's easier and simpler and safer to read/write with `.data()`.  It may be that you can't use `.attr()` to write a custom property like that.  You would probably have to use `.prop()`, but in any case `.data()` is better for this use.  Also, check out the other hint I added to my answer.

Comment: I foud chaining with ";" clearer since I can have up to 10/11 one. Is the a difference in execution ?

Comment: My recommendation of chaining is more efficient because it isn't making a new jQuery object for every method - it's just reusing the same one from the previous call.